# Trying to connect with test.mosquitto.org:8883/ 8884 (ssl connection) Getting the error as below

Tags: ssl, mqtt, raspberry-pi3, publish-subscribe, mosquitto

I am running this in raspberry pi
Firstly I have generated ca.key using

```
    openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 2048
    openssl req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
```

created server certificate using

```
    openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
       openssl req -new -out server.csr -key server.key
       openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key 
       CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 360
```

and created client.key and client.crt using same steps as that of server.

```
     mosquitto_pub --cert client.crt --key client.key -h 
     test.mosquitto.org -p 8883 -m "hellohibye"  -i c10dd3be-a258478f- 
     b7aa-da9aa734a373 -t ack/c10dd3be-a258-478f-b7aa-da9aa734a373 -d
```

when I try to run the command in same working directory, this is the error I am getting

```
     Client c10dd3be-a258-478f-b7aa-da9aa734a373 sending CONNECT OpenSSL 
     Error: error:1416F086:SSL 
     routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
     Error: A TLS error occurred.
```

this is my client.crt looks like:

```
  openssl x509 -text -noout -in client.crt
  Certificate:
  Data:
    Version: 1 (0x0)
    Serial Number:
        15:d3:db:e7:b0:cc:76:e8:67:01:5c:a0:73:48:85:77:c5:1d:bd:af
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C = in, ST = ka, O = livn, CN = test.mosquitto.org
    Validity
        Not Before: Jul 29 08:38:24 2021 GMT
        Not After : Jul 24 08:38:24 2022 GMT
    Subject: C = in, ST = ba, L = ka, O = livn, CN = 
  test.mosquitto.org
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
            Modulus:
                00:9f:bd:44:c0:4c:34:a2:1b:9b:90:b6:ff:7b:41:
                c5:70:9d:34:a0:a9:f5:c6:ee:12:41:07:49:bc:c6:
                fb:2e:74:3c:91:7d:b5:dd:d0:8a:b5:96:ab:fa:32:
                79:15:0c:fb:9a:90:3a:87:68:2a:27:39:67:e8:38:
                6b:46:86:f8:82:18:a2:10:15:3a:cf:e4:61:69:45:
                47:72:67:79:fd:c6:b4:91:79:a8:64:fe:e3:0e:a4:
                34:6f:e6:59:3d:43:33:4d:0b:63:e7:9b:b8:c9:d6:
                85:6b:90:c1:5a:06:ee:07:fb:b9:8f:9c:9f:9b:e7:
                4c:b6:c5:91:4b:d4:da:7c:9a:11:bf:dd:92:7b:33:
                d2:6c:9a:e9:37:9a:62:cf:bc:13:f1:42:b4:b0:3c:
                a1:9d:e5:07:86:43:f4:11:04:1c:59:e2:61:9c:c0:
                47:05:a2:ed:6c:2b:57:69:af:d2:3c:50:e4:39:b2:
                d6:b3:89:55:1e:ba:6d:47:89:7a:b5:38:e5:1b:4a:
                dd:ce:18:13:35:0e:41:f4:5a:ae:e2:52:9e:a6:10:
                af:be:bc:53:e9:4a:6c:4b:34:39:54:2d:45:77:68:
                05:06:5e:8a:5d:98:76:8f:fb:5a:cd:14:b8:ef:74:
                74:8c:8a:60:d0:be:2b:96:37:bd:ce:eb:15:c7:c4:
                00:65
            Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
     54:81:c9:4a:10:6e:2d:be:9a:10:01:60:45:54:3e:50:8a:79:
     15:0a:be:5a:0b:f9:c7:04:39:d8:50:52:a0:85:ba:ad:f7:ac:
     f6:49:d1:70:3f:49:b9:ef:3b:ff:ee:20:48:25:7a:34:b3:f0:
     f8:b8:ca:8d:0d:02:07:cc:ef:22:05:64:96:9a:69:70:14:b2:
     71:ed:96:f1:cf:fc:51:a2:92:c6:3f:03:42:d7:8b:b1:5b:14:
     24:12:fc:96:b8:5f:c2:e8:59:13:f3:6c:39:b2:c5:09:04:00:
     c6:fd:ff:7c:9a:b9:84:d5:0c:ff:db:07:7c:98:ba:e8:dd:c3:
     4e:5d:27:5b:5b:80:22:b0:bb:78:2b:a2:7c:a8:9c:cd:d8:bb:
     c2:be:2c:9f:c1:44:c3:9a:1d:48:3f:66:4d:72:ba:1a:cf:8a:
     3a:fe:a2:85:12:67:2d:a8:ea:a0:e8:5f:cf:10:16:a0:1e:f2:
     2d:db:6c:01:4d:cd:15:11:46:9a:23:e4:9f:ea:1a:23:db:ac:
     2a:e5:9e:37:55:ef:bd:d4:bb:2e:03:78:8e:c0:f2:7d:68:3b:
     c7:91:0e:50:e4:24:30:af:c2:61:93:32:c5:cb:5f:58:19:3a:
     d9:27:a9:b3:44:15:5f:4b:45:be:0f:72:f3:f7:e6:5e:96:35:
     58:03:66:2b
```

and this is my server.crt

```
   openssl x509 -text -noout -in server.crt
      Certificate:
     Data:
    Version: 1 (0x0)
    Serial Number:
        15:d3:db:e7:b0:cc:76:e8:67:01:5c:a0:73:48:85:77:c5:1d:bd:ad
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C = in, ST = ka, O = livn, CN = test.mosquitto.org
    Validity
        Not Before: Jul 29 07:50:34 2021 GMT
        Not After : Jul 24 07:50:34 2022 GMT
      Subject: C = in, ST = ka, O = livn, CN = test.mosquitto.org
      Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
            Modulus:
                00:c6:a3:cb:c0:36:ae:0f:06:c4:d4:d4:0b:2f:c5:
                0f:58:35:98:de:56:fd:67:19:25:f6:eb:a7:e2:7b:
                41:c8:ef:a8:6e:33:61:f7:62:cd:b3:82:49:c1:e6:
                4e:1c:cb:f8:f2:56:c7:b7:fa:af:3e:bd:19:0e:b4:
                32:9f:4f:45:af:95:9f:27:00:56:18:0f:10:58:3c:
                8e:90:f1:2b:e7:9a:8c:07:5b:48:06:7d:70:58:e8:
                ea:38:1d:43:fc:1a:07:58:ee:b5:d3:2e:2f:e7:7d:
                ed:1c:8c:4e:ab:a3:34:3e:9a:49:7d:85:b2:7d:8b:
                c6:b5:90:df:e4:24:5c:78:81:ce:52:be:5f:b9:27:
                5e:19:07:ff:c9:f0:04:0d:73:96:c1:ca:18:58:79:
                6e:0b:ef:cd:ab:9d:00:d4:e9:7e:b4:53:01:72:86:
                ec:e7:87:0d:90:97:df:6f:13:4f:c0:3b:4c:17:7f:
                12:09:08:87:47:75:5a:f6:c8:e6:cc:70:29:47:42:
                53:c6:5f:ff:0b:40:58:06:8d:e3:14:e5:f1:bc:15:
                fa:08:56:1b:c5:13:80:2c:e2:ee:71:c1:2d:c8:3b:
                cf:59:a3:fb:7d:64:32:6e:8f:e9:78:b5:57:9d:24:
                09:fd:bd:33:47:dd:6c:74:1d:90:21:c4:4e:9a:05:
                6a:69
            Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
      Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
     c1:8a:8d:87:23:df:8a:30:74:7a:c8:88:b5:a8:88:f9:e3:80:
     c2:c0:10:1d:da:3c:22:d2:fc:88:49:6c:b4:72:6e:07:e4:95:
     01:c7:f4:f0:bc:d6:3f:3d:26:4e:cf:fa:9a:1e:35:e8:e6:bc:
     e6:cc:dd:56:dc:df:65:bf:ab:56:fa:ab:f7:8c:84:17:da:7d:
     c5:01:a3:0f:48:7a:34:14:68:68:00:52:83:d3:8b:5e:9d:8e:
     71:84:17:c7:15:f9:21:de:5f:47:85:44:6e:5b:89:87:50:33:
     3a:a2:43:88:07:6e:cc:b3:bd:07:91:a0:dc:ef:0a:b8:cb:80:
     f3:54:6c:2e:15:13:35:c8:73:f8:8a:1d:84:c8:67:9a:02:9f:
     90:66:18:a6:e6:22:52:f8:d6:3a:b6:87:bc:73:55:e2:69:66:
     03:f2:34:57:af:9c:4b:33:6c:47:f1:d0:1a:ed:9c:53:c3:1a:
     1e:16:21:4e:74:ad:94:a8:a5:f4:3b:da:87:f3:73:02:ec:6f:
     84:eb:a0:16:77:ce:71:0b:89:62:b9:c7:f8:96:a9:83:a7:fe:
     24:4f:2e:a6:95:f7:7c:9d:b3:85:7d:66:50:5c:ad:8a:01:78:
     c0:95:86:2d:05:60:d3:6e:90:19:da:a9:cc:67:94:50:06:94:
     ed:d4:7e:66
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Tried to connect with 8884 port then also getting this error

```
mosquitto_pub --cafile ca.crt --cert client.crt --key client.key  -h test.mosquitto.org -p 8884 -t test -m "hello there" -i c1 -d
Client c1 sending CONNECT
OpenSSL Error: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Error: A TLS error occurred.
```

Comment: You are using the wrong `ca.crt` read the section of the test.mosquitto.org page I have added to my answer. You should be using the `mosquitto.org.crt` file

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have not supplied a valid hostname.

```
-h test.mosquitto.org:8883
```

You need to provide the port number separately

```
 -h test.mosquitto.org -p 8883
```

You also need to use the correct CA certificate to verify the test.mosquitto.org broker:

From the test.mosquitto.org web page:

> The encrypted ports support TLS v1.3, v1.2 or v1.1 with x509
> certificates and require client support to connect. For ports 8883 and
> 8884 you should use the certificate authority file (mosquitto.org.crt
> ([PEM format](https://test.mosquitto.org/ssl/mosquitto.org.crt)), or mosquitto.org.der ([DER format](https://test.mosquitto.org/ssl/mosquitto.org.der))) to verify the server
> connection. Port 8081 has a Lets Encrypt certificate, so you should
> use your system CA certificates or the appropriate Lets Encrypt CA
> certificate for verification.

Also from the website:

> - 1883 : MQTT, unencrypted, unauthenticated
> - 1884 : MQTT, unencrypted, authenticated
> - 8883 : MQTT, encrypted, unauthenticated
> - 8884 : MQTT, encrypted, client certificate required
> - 8885 : MQTT, encrypted, authenticated
> - 8887 : MQTT, encrypted, server certificate deliberately expired
> - 8080 : MQTT over WebSockets, unencrypted, unauthenticated
> - 8081 : MQTT over WebSockets, encrypted, unauthenticated
> - 8090 : MQTT over WebSockets, unencrypted, authenticated
> - 8091 : MQTT over WebSockets, encrypted, authenticated

This clearly states that if you want to use client certificate authentication you need to use port 8884 not 8883.

Comment: That is irrelevant to the error. The error is clearly about not being able to resolve the host provided. You need to change the `-h` provided to mosquitto_pub to the `-h` & `-p` I have shown. It's not even getting close to looking at the certificates you've generated

Comment: But no, the CN should describe you, not the broker.

Comment: I have tried with                                                                                                                  -h test.mosquitto.org  -p 8883                                                                                                             error i am getting is Error: The connection was lost. @hardillb

Comment: You also need to supply either `--cafile` or `--capath` to enable a TLS connection